# Selenium with Node.js: can't stop loop execution

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, promise

I've wrote some test with Selenium and Node.js, but when I run that test, it never ends.

My code is:

```
driver.wait(function () {
    return driver.executeScript('return document.readyState').then(function (readyState) {
        if (readyState === 'complete') {
            doTest();
            // HERE I WANT TO EXIT
        };
    });
});
```

The method `doTest()` is called infinitely times.

And where now you can see "`HERE I WANT TO EXIT`" I tried to stop the loop with:

```
return true;
return false;
resolve();
driver.close();
driver.quit();
```

But none worked, any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear why `return true;` does not work. The possible issue is that `doTest()` fails with some exception which is propagated by the wait. Did you check that your code get to the line "HERE I WANT TO EXIT"?

I would suggest either adding a `console.log` after `doTest()` to make sure the doTest() is completed successfully

or make doTest() return true if everything is ok and false if there was any exception and make it as

```
    if (readyState === 'complete') {
        return doTest();
    };
```

Comment: I can't solve my problem... but probably what you say is correct. Thanks.